# Why does after adding .torrent file in deluge, it errors?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, file-sharing, deluge

here's a screenshot. i figured after changing the target directory to /media/exthdd from /home/pi which is the default. i cannot understand why it wont accept my hdd, it just errors, the default directory seems ok

Comment: Check your permissions on that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a NTFS HDD. NTFS does not support UNIX permissions.

You need to either change the mount arguments of your HDD, or reformat as ext4 (the better option, NTFS eats tonnes of CPU too so you really need ext4 if you're doing a media center or streaming hub).

[This might help with formatting the HDD](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disk-format/).